# VBA Replace() in a loop with type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I'm fairly new to VBA, and I'm just trying to replace any character, "NA", "ZZ", "Z", in column "N" and "O" with "0". The following is a loop with `if` statement, but for some reason I kept on getting

> runtime 13 error with type mismatch

Could anyone help me to fix the error?

Thanks!

```
Dim v as String
sym = Array("NA", "ZZ", "Z")

  If Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("N") Then
   For Each a In sym
    v = Replace(v, a, "0")
   Next a

 ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("O") Then
   For Each a In sym
     v = Replace(v, a, "0")
   Next a

 End If
```

Comment: what is your intention with `If Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("N") Then`

Comment: @ScottCraner To define column N. I only want to replace characters in array `sym` that appear in column N and O. Maybe there is a more efficient way to do so?

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("N")` does not return a Boolean.

Comment: and v is a empty string, so no matter how many time you loop it will remain an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like so. It's good practice to specify the [various parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-replace-method-excel).

```
sym = Array("NA", "ZZ", "Z")

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N:O")
    For Each a In sym
        .Cells.Replace what:=a, replacement:=0
   Next a
End With
```

Comment: if you define `Range("N:O")` does it mean selecting columns from N to O. What if I only what to perform the action in column N and O, excluding the ones in between? Shouldn't it be `Range("N,O") `?

Comment: Which ones did you have in mind between N and O!? You can use `Range("N:N,P:P")` to exclude O, though better still to limit the range rather than check the whole column.

Comment: I simply just want to check column N and O, `Range(N:O)` seems to select all columns from N to O.  Or in VBA, is it the same to define `Range(N:N, O:O)` as `Range(N:O)`?

Comment: Eh? There are no columns between N and O.

Comment: OMG...the sun is baking my brain .. haha XD... thanks for the remind.

Comment: That's ok, one thing I'm pretty confident on is my alphabet.

Comment: One last question, how do I incorporate `SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True` in the loop?

Comment: I think I figured out.

Comment: It's in the link above - there's an example further downn. Come back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to loop over the cells, try:

```
Sub lydias()
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N:O")
        .Replace What:="NA", replacement:="0"
        .Replace What:="ZZ", replacement:="0"
        .Replace What:="Z", replacement:="0"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim sym As Variant
sym = Array("NA", "ZZ", "Z")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim colums_range As Range

With ws
Set colums_range = Union(.Columns("N").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .Columns("O").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
End With

   For Each element In sym

    colums_range.Replace What:=CStr(element), Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

   Next element

End Sub
```